# What is the ECM used in building fcitx?

Tags: cmake, fcitx

I am trying to rebuild fcitx on Xenial (16.04.3) so that I can debug the failure to respond to R-ALT when using an M17N input method.  My attempt to rebuild fcitx fails with the error message:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):   Could not find a
>   package configuration file provided by "ECM" (requested   version
>   0.0.11) with any of the following names:
>
> ```
> ECMConfig.cmake
> ecm-config.cmake
> ```

Answer (score 9):

ECM stands for Extra CMake Modules. It adds additional modules to your cmake installation. See [the manual here](https://api.kde.org/ecm/manual/ecm.7.html).

On Ubuntu (or any other Debian based system), you can install it with

```
sudo apt install extra-cmake-modules
```

Once that's done, fcitx build should be able to continue if all other dependencies are also satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

An immediate practical answer to my question is given in the 'Error List' section of http://www.d3rm.org/Programming_Language/z.Programmer%27s_Toolkit/FCITX_-_Free_Chinese_Input_Toy_for_X/1.Installation.html .  One doesn't need to be able to read Chinese to understand the solutions.

However, the correct approach would have been to use `apt-get build-dep...`  That command asks before installing.

I still hit a problem with rebuilding even after using `apt-get build-dep`, but I managed to rebuild enough to find and implement a solution to my problem.  An intermediate problem was solved by using `apt-get install` when `apt-get build-dep` declined to install a needed package.

Comment: What was the solution that one doesn't need to be able to read Chinese to understand? Because that link 404s.